# How to inform the user that the save was not successful?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, metabox, save-post, notices

When saving a post, i have a meta box in which the user must put something.
If the user input is something when i do not accept, how will i tell him?

```
add_action('save_post' , 'my_save_metaboxe_data');

function my_save_metaboxe_data( $post_id )
{
    ....
    if ( 'something not accepted' )
    {
        return ????? ;
    }
    ....
}
```

I also read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130011/121651) post.

I personally just write a `return;` , but the most important problem i face in this way is it returns the following message to the user:

[image]

What can i do to prevent this message?

I have also studied the wonderful hook [`admin_notices`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices), but i still do not know how to use it to appear when it should be.

So how can i prevent at least the above message? ( *I develop a plugin for WordPress.* )

My question is specific about creating a new **custom post** and for the **meta boxes validations** who i have added. How to handle the save_post action  to return the appropriate messages and not always returning "everything going well".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop showing admin notice after close button has been clicked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242705/how-to-stop-showing-admin-notice-after-close-button-has-been-clicked)

Comment: No, it's not the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Handling admin notice on Edit Post**

When *action* related to `post` or `editpost`, we will be faced with [`redirect_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_post/) function. There are two filters you can use to handle the post messages, `redirect_post_location` and `post_updated_messages` ( see the list messages at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L135 ).

Here the sample code how to handle the messages.

**Create new message (optional)**

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', function( $messages ) {
    //create another message code, i.e 11
    $messages['post'] = $messages['post'] + array( 11 => __( 'Something Wrong', 'textdomain' ) );

    return $messages;
} );
```

**Handling redirection**

```
add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', function( $location, $post_id ) {
    //let say the conditon is false, or you can create your code here
    $condition = false;

    if ( ! $condition ) //add 11 as code message or use in the list post messages
        $location = add_query_arg( 'message', 11, get_edit_post_link( $post_id, 'url' ) );


    return $location;
}, 10, 2 );
```

As those codex reference, code `0` will be give us no notice. The notice will always give update notice (green color), if we need error or warning notice, I suggest to create own admin notice. I hope this help.